Pyscripter: Can't change the path with site packages
I've done a pip install docx and from what I can see this was created on:
C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.12_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python312\site-packages
Running import docx results in a "No module named 'docx'" error, so I checked the Python Path on Pyscripter, which is taking the libraries from
C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.12_3.12.1008.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\Lib\site-packages
I tried adding/replacing the path then running the script again, and for whatever reason PyScripter is defaulting the original path back and the import error persists.
Not sure if I'm missing something fundamental from running PyScripter and Python 3.12 is the only one installed on my computer.

always put FULL error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not in comments) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information in the full error/traceback.

what module do you try to use? Maybe it has different name for install and different name for import.

it seems you have two Python installed and you install module docx for one Python but you run code with other Python. In your code run os.executable() to get /full/path/to/python and use it to install module /full/path/to/python -m pip install ...

if you want to change Python in some IDE then you have to find option where you can set path to python.exe, not to site-packages because paths are built-in in python.exe

correction: sys.executable instead of os.executable()

Full error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\USERNAME\Git\Project1\open.py", line 12, in 
import docx
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'docx'

the install name is python-docx but it function is docx as it appears on https://automatetheboringstuff.com/chapter13/
Running sys.executable shows python on the WindowsApps folder, which should be the only one installed.

read first comment: show in question (not in comments). It will be more readable and more people will see it  - so more people may help.

some IDEs install own version of Python, and later it makes problem because users think they have only one Python, and they use pip in system's shell to install modules but it doesn't install module for Python used by IDE. Maybe Pyscripter has the same problem. And maybe get path from sys.executable  and use it to install modules.
